# How do you make an S3 object public via the aws SDK Android?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to make my upload as public. I was able to upload a image into s3 bucket. But i was unable to make that public by programmatically I am using AWS SDK 2.1.10 Below is my code for uploading image into s3 bucket

```
mUpload = getTransferManager().upload( AmazonConstants.BUCKET_NAME.toLowerCase(Locale.US), /* getPrefix(getContext()) // "android_uploads/" */ locationPath + super.getFileName() /** + "." + mExtension */ , mFile);
```

mUpload.waitForCompletion();

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `PutObjectRequest` in `upload()`.

```
getTransferManager().upload(
    new PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, File file)
   .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
);
```